# Reference request on a formula for the barycenter of the interior of a quadrilateral

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry

Suppose $(x_i,y_i),$ $i=1,2,3,4$ are the vertices of a convex quadrilateral, in order as you follow the boundary (so that $i=1,3$ are opposite points as are $i=2,4.$ I wanted to find the center of gravity of the **interior** of the quadrilateral.

For a triangle it's the same as the center of gravity of the three vertices, so split the quadrilateral into two triangles in two different ways: one in which the two triangles correspond to the indices $1,2,3$ and $3,4,1,$ and one in which they correspond to $2,3,4$ and $4,1,2.$ The point we seek should be on the line between the first two centers of gravity, and also on the line between the next two. Thus
\begin{align}
& r\cdot\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3} 3 + (1-r)\cdot\frac{x_3+x_4+x_1} 3 \\[8pt]
= {} & x\text{-coordinate of the center of gravity} \\[8pt]
= {} & s\cdot\frac{x_2+x_3 + x_4} 3 + (1-s)\cdot \frac{x_4+x_1+x_2} 3.
\end{align}
and then a second equation results from replacement of every $x_i$ by $y_i,$ giving the $y$-coordinate.

Solving for $r$ and $s$ I get
\begin{align}
r & = \frac{(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_3)-(y_3-y_1)(x_2-x_3)}{(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_4) - (y_3-y_1)(x_2-x_4)}, \\[8pt]
1-r & = \frac{(x_3-x_1)(y_3-y_4) - (y_3-y_1)(x_3-x_4)}{(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_4) - (y_3-y_1)(x_2-x_4)}.
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
& x\text{-coordinate of the center of gravity} \\[8pt]
= {} & r\cdot\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3} 3 + (1-r)\cdot\frac{x_3+x_4+x_1} 3 \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4} 3 - \frac 1 3 \cdot \frac{(x_3-x_1)(x_4y_2 - y_4x_2) - (x_2-x_4)(x_1y_3 - x_3 y_1)}{(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_4) - (y_3-y_1)(x_2-x_4)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \cdots\text{etc.}\cdots
\end{align}
and so now we should massage it into some form that has some nice symmetries and simplicity (in particular, readily seen to be invariant under cyclic shifts of the indices $1,2,3,4$), BUT at this point I'm thinking this *must* be in some standard tables and books somewhere. So that is my question: Where is this in the literature?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

Comment: @Ripi2 : It seems your link narrows the search to sources other than that Wikipedia article.

Comment: Scroll down to "References", near the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Ripi2 : You should note that you can link to that section directly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#References

Comment: @Ripi2 : The most relevant among the references appears to be the one by Paul Bourke. That one deals with a variety of topics. Where within it do you find what you had in mind?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is essentially explained by [Möbius](https://books.google.com/books/about/Lehrbuch_der_Statik_von_August_Ferdinand.html?id=Q8cNGljDDpIC) (see p.211-215, section 113), where on page 212, he manipulated with (1), (2) and (3) similar to your formulas, except for different use of coordinates. See also [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q8cNGljDDpIC&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=der%20schwerpunkt%20der%20massen%20Mobius&source=bl&ots=isC0vHYFHa&sig=ACfU3U1AjX6CFm8cPiflOC7rnNxtK24BRQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBmerm2_XqAhV2lHIEHTdTAWcQ6AEwCnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=der%20schwerpunkt%20der%20massen%20Mobius&f=false).